# disable Keith Wood jQuery Calendars Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Keith Wood [jQuery Calendars Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html) (not his [jQuery Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)). In one page, I have many calendar datepicker input (using css as selectors). How to disabled one of them?

```
// js
$('.calendar-input').calendarsPicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    autoSize: true,
    showTrigger: '<img src="calendar.gif">',
});

<!-- html -->
<input type="text" class="calendar-input" name="cal_1" id="cal_1">
<input type="text" class="calendar-input" name="cal_2" id="cal_2">
<input type="text" class="calendar-input" name="cal_3" id="cal_3">
```

Let say I want to disable `cal_3` (user can't pick or edit from that object). If I change `cal_3` class to something else, the object size become expanded (since I use autoSize true) and the calendar button not shown anymore. All I want is just make the size same as others and calender button still show to it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried in some part of your code calling this next line?

```
$('#cal_3').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: ow ... I'm forgot that basic attribute. Thanks Reigel :D